# como levantar requisitos de um projeto

Tags: engenharia-de-software

Bom na minha matéria de modelagem de dados, o professor disse que temos que fazer um projeto, e para fazermos o projeto devemos entrevistar um pessoa que queira o produlto, mas estou com duvidas nas perguntas, o que eu devo perguntar ?, pois as perguntas não podem ter duplo sentido

Comment: Você deve perguntar por tudo aquilo que precisa saber para poder fazer o projeto. É o momento que você não pode supor nada sobre o projeto. Você deve perguntar e confirmar a informação com a resposta.

Answer (score 2):

Essas perguntas dependeram de qual projeto será implementado, tomando como exemplo uma implementação para um restaurante, temos : quantos funcionários possui, será feito reserva de mesas, quais formas de pagamento seram disponíveis, o sistema deverá ter login para funcionários , como seram feitas as reposições para o estoque de suprimentos etc...